# Change time zone for whole column of table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table 'temp' with Temperature and Time as two column. When I feed Temperature then Time is automatically gets printed with 'timestamp' and default 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'. I am showing in graph the output with PHP code. Now I am getting Time in UTC zone where I require it in IST.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM temp;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$chart_data .= "{ Time:'".$row["Time"]."', 
Temperature:".$row["Temperature"]."}, ";
}
```

Pls guide how to change timestamp of UTC to IST for complete column 'Time'

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `date_timezone_set` for $row["Time"] while saving in $chart_data

```
date_timezone_set($date, timezone_open('America/Los_Angeles'));
echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i:sP');
```

You can specify the time zone you want in date_timezone_set.

Or use the more popular OOP interface:

```
// The reference timezone
$date = new DateTime($row['Time'], new DateTimeZone('UTC'));

// Changing the timezone
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimezone('America/Los_Angeles'));

// Output
echo $date->format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i:sP');
```

Comment: how to write your OOP cade in chart_data     $chart_data .= "{ Time:'".$row["Time"]."', 
Temperature:".$row["Temperature"]."}, ";
}

Answer (score 1):

Alternative... TIMESTAMP fields are already timezone aware.

You *could* simply tell mysql to convert the times for you:

```
SET time_zone = 'Asia/Kolkata';
```

If you run this before your query, you should also get the right time. I'm adding this as an option, but I would actually not recommend it. It's better to keep your MySQL connection in UTC and let PHP handle the conversion with `DateTime` and `DateTimezone`

Comment: my server is shared one, can't do this

Comment: This works on a shared server too. The above statement is per connection, so other people are not affected.